# Cannot dump database in Neo4j Desktop on Windows

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-desktop

I  cannot dump a database from Neo4j Desktop on Windows 10. I am using OpenJDK 11, Neo4j Desktop v1.4.11 and the DB version is v4.4.2.

From what I have seen in other posts, this works fine on Linux/Mac but not on Windows. Also, as this is using the Neo4j Desktop interface, I have no control over the path name.

The error I get in the Desktop log file is:

```
[error] Selecting JVM - Version:11.0.8+10-LTS, Name:OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Vendor:Azul Systems, Inc.
java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 143: C:\Users\Glen Rutherford\AppData\Local\Neo4j\Relate\Data\projects\project-808d9e7f-36da-4a8e-a49e-7036d2129eb2\dev-strategy-neo4j-7-Jan-2022-12:29:54.dump
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(WindowsPathParser.java:182)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:153)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:92)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:229)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Path.of(Path.java:147)
    at org.neo4j.commandline.dbms.DumpCommand.openDumpStream(DumpCommand.java:142)
    at org.neo4j.commandline.dbms.DumpCommand.dump(DumpCommand.java:154)
    at org.neo4j.commandline.dbms.DumpCommand.execute(DumpCommand.java:115)
    at org.neo4j.cli.AbstractCommand.call(AbstractCommand.java:71)
    at org.neo4j.cli.AbstractCommand.call(AbstractCommand.java:34)
    at picocli.CommandLine.executeUserObject(CommandLine.java:1953)
    at picocli.CommandLine.access$1300(CommandLine.java:145)
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.executeUserObjectOfLastSubcommandWithSameParent(CommandLine.java:2352)
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2346)
    at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2311)
    at picocli.CommandLine$AbstractParseResultHandler.execute(CommandLine.java:2179)
    at picocli.CommandLine.execute(CommandLine.java:2078)
    at org.neo4j.cli.AdminTool.execute(AdminTool.java:93)
    at org.neo4j.cli.AdminTool.main(AdminTool.java:79)
```

Comment: Not sure why this has been marked down. I have done research, I have read similar posts to this on Stackoverflow, none of which address this specific issue ie Neo4j Desktop on Windows. I have also read through the Neo4j documentation. This issue seems to me, to be a bug in Neo4j Desktop on Windows as the a Windows path always contains a colon and the exception states that a colon is an illegal character.

Comment: What command are you using to create the dump? Have you tried to keep it simple first by simply dumping to the current folder?

Comment: Hi @Richard, I am using the UI in Neo4j Desktop, which doesn't prompt for a location. So the error is produced by Neo4j Desktop itself. I have tried the command line approach but it also seems incompatible with Windows as I get this error: `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM, should be none for all except owner` in respect to Java ACL

Comment: I have not used the UI to make a Neo4J dump previously. In fact I have not seen an option - I am using 1.4.11 too, but most of my DBs are pre 4.0. I use the terminal and type the command with no problems.  I have created a 4.4.2 DB to confirm the Terminal option is still valid.

Comment: Found the dump option for the V4 database after I stopped the running V3. I get the same error if I try to dump from the UI.

Comment: Hi Glen, I just read your comment below. I wanted to clarify that I am working with Neo4j Desktop on Windows 10. I am getting the same UI error as you, but I do not get any CLI errors. I do not use the standard Windows Command Prompt - I fire it off from inside Neo4j - via the `Terminal` option in the menu.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.